# When copying in linux do permissions and owners persist?

Tags: linux, permissions

When I copy with a command such as:

```
cp -R /myfolder /home/backup/
```

Will the permissions such as `775 (drwxr-xr-x)` persist?

Will the owner `'danny:danny'` persist, or will the owner change to the person who actually made the copy?

Answer (score 1):

you can run `cp -a` to preserve the ownership. Note that to preserve root permissions, you must run with `sudo`.

Without this flag, ownership is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

If a user copy a file he will become the owner of it.

```
$ mkdir d1 && touch d1/f1
$ sudo cp -R d1 d2
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Oct 28 17:58 d2
$ ls -l d2/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        0 Oct 28 17:58 f1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is cp -p to preserve the timestamps,ownership and permissions check out http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker